# Missing argument list for class template

Tags: c++

I have this error: Missing argument list for class template for this code when I use Screen constructor `Screen(char*)`

```
int main()
{
    const char* chars = "chars";
    Screen<300, 300> s1 = Screen(chars);

}
```

```
template <size_t height, size_t width>
class Screen
{
private:
 /*
    ...
 */

public:
    Screen(char*);
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Comment: The compiler cannot determine the type parameters for `Screen` in the expression `Screen(chars)`; You need to go with e.g. `auto s1 = Screen<300, 300>(chars);`

Comment: Or alternatively just the old-fashioned `Screen<300, 300> s1(chars);` or, confusingly, `Screen<300, 300> s1 =chars;` (because the constructor isn't `explicit`. You'll also need to make the constructor `const char*`

Comment: @Elliott Except `Screen<300, 300> s1 = chars;`  wouldn't work because `Screen` takes a non-`const` `char*`

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! It works with replacing ```const char*``` with ```char*``` and adding ```Screen<300, 300>(chars)```.

Comment: @Liza Replacing `const char*` with `char*` doesn't sound right though. You may want to replace `char*` with `const char*` instead. `char* chars = "chars";` isn't valid C++.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh yeah, sorry